# How to add element into collection and then create subcollection in this document?

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I have list of dicts (these are documents in my future Firestore collection). And every document has a list of dicts as a field (I want this list to be a subcollection inside each document). At my case data is list of tournaments and every tournament has list of players. [tournaments.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8TwD.png)

I need to add player as as a document into participants subcollection in each tournament.

I've tried to do:

```
for tournament in tournaments:
    participants = tournament['participants']
    del tournament['participants']
    document_reference = db.collection('tournaments').document()
    document_reference.set(tournament)
    
    for player in participants:
        document_reference.collection('participants').add(player)
```

I don't understand how that works and how firestore add documents into subcollection when ID of document haven't generated yet.

Answer (score 0):

Check the docs [here](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/collection.html). `db.collection('tournaments').document()` is returning a reference to the document. In your code, you are not defining the document id explicitly, so it is being autogenerated. Then, using that reference to the document, you are creating a new subcollection associated with that specific document. You can read more about references and subcollections [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).